# Does updating the expirationTime of a table via the Google BigQuery API also update the GBQ UI?

Tags: api, google-bigquery

Forgive me for asking such a simple question, I've been asked to look into this on behalf of some Developers I work with.

When using the BigQuery API to update the [expirationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#expirationTime) property for an existing or new table, will the changes be visible in the BigQuery UI once the update has occured? It would make sense that this does happen, but I wanted to double check.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running this on dummy table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will update in the BigQuery UI once the update has occurred.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Code Sample:

```
import datetime

from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project='elzagales')
project = client.project
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, 'so_test')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('table_1')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request

assert table.expires is None

# set table to expire 5 days from now
expiration = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + datetime.timedelta(
    days=5
)
table.expires = expiration
table = client.update_table(table, ["expires"])  # API request

# expiration is stored in milliseconds
margin = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1000)
assert expiration - margin <= table.expires <= expiration + margin
```

example reference:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time